# Disable a gradle plugin depending on the java target

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, gradle-plugin, sonarqube-scan

I'm using Gradle 3 and Sonarqube on a Java7 project: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/build.gradle

And my ci is Travis with Java7 & Java8: https://travis-ci.org/cbeust/testng/

Only recent versions of the Sonarqube plugin support Gradle 3 and they only run on a Java8 runtime.
When I run the Gradle build with Java7 then it fails with `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonarqube/gradle/SonarQubePlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`

I tried to enable the SonarQube plugin with Java8 only but it fails too: 
https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/update-gradle-plugins/build.gradle

I tried to define the SonarQube plugin in an external gradle file but Gradle allows the plugin definition in the main file only.

I'd like to avoid the duplication of the `build.gradle`.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the plugins DSL not auto-apply the plugin and apply it manually like

```
plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.2.1"
}

apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
```

then you should be able to put the applying into a separate Gradle file, or only apply it depending on any condition you can formulate with Groovy.